# How to make stacked cards animate to go behind each other

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

I am trying to make a PageView with only 2 items. But I want to see the card behind the first one. And when swipe it to the right I want it to animate to the back and the back card animate to the front.
[image]

I have found a similar solution but not quite it,
[Flutter Swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper#controller). It does allow me to see the card behind however it's not as much as I want and it doesn't animate to the back instead it just disappears to the right. Also, I want to make it "pop-out" on the right and not on the left.

[image]

Any help would be useful to point me in a direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the order of the children of `Stack` when needed:

```
var children = <Widget>[Widget1(), Widget2()];
Stack(
  children: children,
)
```

when `Widget2()`'s position has been animated to the edge:

```
setState((){
  children = <Widget>[Widget2(), Widget1()];
});
```

Comment: How would I do that animated to the edge part?

Comment: Use `Positioned()` widget